# Show that $A_{1},B_{1},C_{1}$ are on a straight line which is perpendicular to $OI$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Triangle $ABC$ has a circumcircle $(O)$ and a incircle $(I)$. The external bisectors of $\angle A, \angle B,\angle C$ cut $BC,CA,AB$ at $A_{1},B_{1},C_{1}$. Show that $A_{1},B_{1},C_{1}$ are on a straight line which is perpendicular to $OI$.

I think that, first we prove $A_{1},B_{1},C_{1}$ are on a straight line by Menelaus theorem. But how to prove this line is perpendicular to $OI$????

Can anyone help me please? Thank all of you.

Comment: Could you attach an image?

Comment: Are O and I centers of the circles? What you mean by external bisectors? are you defining the triangle sides as lines? - A drawing will help.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**PART ONE:** Let us first prove that points $A_1$, $B_1$ and $C_1$ are collinear.

By applying law of sines to triangle $\triangle ACC_1$:

$${AC_1 \over AC}={\sin\angle ACC_1 \over \sin\angle AC_1C}={\sin(90^\circ-\frac\gamma2) \over \sin\angle AC_1C}\tag{1}$$

By applying law of sines to triangle $\triangle BCC_1$:

$${BC_1 \over BC}={\sin\angle BCC_1 \over \sin\angle AC_1C}={\sin(90^\circ+\frac\gamma2) \over \sin\angle AC_1C}\tag{2}$$

Notice that $\sin(90^\circ-\frac\gamma2)=\sin(90^\circ+\frac\gamma2)$. From (1) and (2) it is obvious that:

$${AC_1 \over AC}={BC_1 \over BC}$$

$${AC_1 \over BC_1}={b \over a}\tag{3}$$

BTW, this simple relation can be obtianed in a dozen of different ways, I just quoted the first that came to my mind.

In exactly the same way you can show that:

$${BA_1 \over CA_1}={c \over b},\quad {CB_1 \over AB_1}={a \over c}\tag{4}$$

From (3) and (4):

$${AC_1 \over BC_1}\times{BA_1 \over CA_1}\times{CB_1 \over AB_1}=1$$

...so by [Menelaus's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem), points $A_1$, $B_1$ and $C_1$ are collinear.

**PART TWO:** Let us now prove that $OI\bot A_1B_1C_1$ (a pretty amazing property, at least to me :)

Notice the shortest side of triangle $ABC$. In our case that is, for example, $AC$. Pick points $C'\in BC$ and $A'\in AB$ such that $AC=CC'=AA'=b$.

> **LEMMA:** Lines $OI$ and $A'C'$ are perpendicular!
>
> The fact that $OI\bot A'C'$ is actually well know and you can find several different proofs [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h14655). Ignore the first post in the the thread because it is tied to a particular value of angle $\angle B$. Just skip it and focus on a general statement of Darij Grinberg (third post in the thread). His proof is not the simplest one and you should scroll down a little bit and check Yptsoi's short and very ellegant answer. The last proof in the same thread is also very interesting.
>
> The same problem is discussed in several other places on the web  [[1]](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/InAndCircumcenter.shtml#Explanation)[[2]](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/InAndCircumcenterB.shtml).

Now, let us prove that triangles $\triangle A_1BC_1$ and $\triangle C'BA'$ are similar. Let us start from (3):

$${AC_1 \over BC_1}={b \over a}$$

$${BC_1 - AB\over BC_1}={b \over a}$$

$$1-{c \over BC_1}={b \over a}$$

$$BC_1={ac \over a-b}\tag{5}$$

Using the same approach:

$$BA_1={ac \over c-b}\tag{6}$$

It is also obvious that:

$$BA'=c-b\tag{7}$$

$$BC'=a-b\tag{8}$$

From (5), (6), (7) and (8):

$$\frac{BC_1}{BA'}=\frac{ac}{(a-b)(c-b)}=\frac{BA_1}{BC}\tag{9}$$

Triangles $\triangle A_1BC_1$ and $\triangle C'BA'$ also share the same angle $B$ so by (9) they are proved to be similar.

This simply means that $A'C' \parallel A_1C_1$ (red lines in the picture). Our **LEMMA** states that $OI\bot A'C'$ and therefore $OI\bot A_1B_1C_1$.